# save string array in binary format

Tags: c#, string, binaryfiles

```
string value1 , value1 ;
int length1 , length2 ;
System.Collections.BitArray bitValue1 = new System.Collections.BitArray(Length1);
System.Collections.BitArray bitValue2 = new System.Collections.BitArray(Length2);
```

I'm looking for the fastest way to covert each string to BitArray with defined length for each string (the string should be trimmed if it is larger than defined length and if strings size is smaller remaining bits will be filled with false) and then put this two strings together and write it in a binary file .

Edit :
@dtb : a simple example can be like this value1 = "A" ,value2 = "B" and length1 =8 and length2 = 16 and the result will be 010000010000000001000010 
the first 8 bits are from "A" and next 16 bits from "B"

Comment: Why do you need the BitArray?

Comment: I dont need the bitarray if there is any other way . but consider that the length can be any number (perhaps 2 bits)

Comment: What is the content of the string? Can you please enclose some code to explain more as to what you are trying to achieve for us SO'ers?

Comment: strings can contain anything (integer , boolean , strings , ... but all are converted to string )

Comment: Can you post an example of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Are you only using ASCII 127 and less? If not you're still going to have to take encoding into consideration. For instance, the string "Heÿ" has a length of 3 but a UTF-8 byte count of 4 and UTF-16 byte count of 6.

Comment: @Chris yes I'm only using ASCII 127 chars

Comment: What if the lengths are not multiples of 8? And do I understand it right that inputs with less than the specified bits should be padded left and not right?

Comment: @dtb : yes thats right , actually I'm trying to write a part of an application which will let the user create his/her binary format and then save the data into file with created format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //Source string
        string value1 = "t";
        //Length in bits
        int length1 = 2;
        //Convert the text to an array of ASCII bytes
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value1);
        //Create a temp BitArray from the bytes
        System.Collections.BitArray tempBits = new System.Collections.BitArray(bytes);
        //Create the output BitArray setting the maximum length
        System.Collections.BitArray bitValue1 = new System.Collections.BitArray(length1);
        //Loop through the temp array
        for(int i=0;i<tempBits.Length;i++)
        {
            //If we're outside of the range of the output array exit
            if (i >= length1) break;
            //Otherwise copy the value from the temp to the output
            bitValue1.Set(i, tempBits.Get(i));                
        }
```

And I'm going to keep saying it, this assumes ASCII characters so anything above ASCII 127 (such as the é in résumé) will freak out and probably return ASCII 63 which is the question mark.

Comment: Thank you cheris I edited the code a little and now it's working good . BTW I found this which may help others who wants to do binary data saving : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/bitstream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When converting a string to something else you need to consider what encoding you want to use. Here's a version that uses UTF-8

```
bitValue1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value1, 0, length1);
```

**Edit**
Hmm... saw that you're looking for a BitArray and not a ByteArray, this won't help you probably.

Comment: the length1 is the Number of bits .

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a very clear question I'll give this a shot nonetheless,

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
public static void RunSnippet()
{
   string s = "123";
   byte[] b = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
   System.Collections.BitArray bArr = new System.Collections.BitArray(b);
   Console.WriteLine("bArr.Count = {0}", bArr.Count);
   for(int i = 0; i < bArr.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLin(string.Format("{0}", bArr.Get(i).ToString()));
   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream("test.bin", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew)){
    bf.Serialize(fStream, (System.Collections.BitArray)bArr);
    Console.WriteLine("Serialized to test.bin");
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.